# Swift image resize when scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, image, swift, scrollview

i am trying to achieve this image animation?

its autoayout and image resize. Does anyone know how to do this?

[here is what am i looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpPdW.gif)

here is my code

```
 /*
* Image resizing
*/
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let top: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let newWidth: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.size.width
    let new: CGFloat = 200 - top
    if top >= -64 {
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 - top, self.view.bounds.size.width, 220)
        //imageView.si
    }
    if top < -64 {
        var imgViewRect: CGRect = self.imageView.frame
        imgViewRect.size.height = new
        imgViewRect.size.width = newWidth - top
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(32 + (top / 2), 64, self.view.frame.size.width - (top + 64), imgViewRect.size.height - 44)

    }
}
```

Comment: *This effect is called parallax effect*. BTW question is not appropriate here. You need to show what you have tried to achieve that and where you stuck. You will get lots of example on Google for this effect.

Comment: ok i edit my question..thx for reply

Comment: Instead of playing with frames, you have to try `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` of imageView, that will work definitely.

Comment: cmon bro....cant u help me out more bro? :-)

Comment: I didn't code it. I'll code it as soon as I get time, and will post answer.

Comment: @Kampai any chances to post code soon? :-) thank you